# Javascript reduce() until sum of values < variable

Tags: javascript, json, reduce

I am fetching an array of video durations (in seconds) from a JSON file in Javascript, that, to simplify, would look like this:

```
array = [30, 30, 30]
```

I would like to add each value to the previous value until a condition is met (the sum being less than a variable x) and then to get both the new value and the index position in the array of the video to play.

For example if x=62 (condition), I would like the first two values in the array to be added (from my understanding reduce() is appropriate here), and the index = 2 (the second video in the array).

I've got the grasp of reduce():

```
var count = array.reduce(function(prev, curr, index) {
                    console.log(prev, curr, index);
                    return prev + curr;
                });
```

But can't seem to get beyond this point.. Thanks

Comment: why not use `for` loop?

Comment: i agree about the for, since you need to break early and return 2 values (index and sum)

Comment: or a while loop would work. while(total < threshold && i < array.length) { total+= array[i]; i++;}

Comment: @Mic it wouldn't work if the first value > threshold

Comment: @Utopik That's an awfully easy thing to check. Several of the actual answers will fail on the same case.

Comment: oh, let's not talk about the answers, they are really low quality. But you're right about the while loop, I think I was thinking about a do/while, not a while :facepalm:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which breaks on a condition.

```js
var array = [30, 30, 30],
    x = 62,
    index,
    sum = 0;
    
array.some(function (a, i) {
    index = i;
    if (sum + a > x) {
        return true;
    }
    sum += a;
});

console.log(index, sum);
```

With a compact result and this args

```js
var array = [30, 30, 30],
    x = 62,
    result = { index: -1, sum: 0 };
    
array.some(function (a, i) {
    this.index = i;
    if (this.sum + a > x) {
        return true;
    }
    this.sum += a;
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is the one. Less code and returns when condition is met, so doesn't loop through whole array :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of some() but this was exactly what I was looking for - thanks.

Comment: This is advertising bad practices. Array.some is not meant to do that, the code is hard to read (having one letter variable names doesn't help). The function you're passing to Array.some is reading outside of its scope. I'm afraid this looks like a hack to me. If there is no reduceUntil function, we can still use a good old for loop to solve that problem

Comment: @Utopik, sorry, *"is not meant to do that"*, is saying who? if you mean clean callbacks which are pure functions, then you are right, but this was actually not the point. there are only two array methods who allows to exit early and that is what i use here.

Comment: In this case, I don't think there is a necessity to use an array method.

Comment: @Utopik, right. for performance issues, i would take a for or while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [2,4,5,7,8];
var index;
var result = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(a, b,i) {
  var sum = a+b;
  if(sum<11){
    index=i;
    return sum;
  }
}, 2);
console.log(result,index);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a for loop? This is hack-free:

```
function sumUntil(array, threshold) {
    let i
    let result = 0

    // we loop til the end of the array
    // or right before result > threshold
    for(i = 0; i < array.length && result+array[i] < threshold; i++) {
        result += array[i]
    }

    return {
        index: i - 1, // -1 because it is incremented at the end of the last loop
        result
    }
}

console.log(
    sumUntil( [30, 30, 30], 62 ) 
) 
// {index: 1, result: 60}
```

bonus: replace `let` with `var` and it works on IE5.5

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```js
    var limit = 60;
    var array = [30,30,30];
    var count = array.reduce(function(prev, curr, index) {
      var temp = prev.sum + curr;
      if (index != -1) {
        if (temp > limit) {
          prev.index = index;
        } else {
          prev.sum = temp;
        }
      }
      return prev;
    }, {
      sum: 0,
      index: -1
    });

    console.log(count);
```

Comment: That is currently still iterating over the whole array though. Not really ideal.

Comment: @mic, that is true. I was under the assumption the OP **had** to use `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

What about this : https://jsfiddle.net/rtcgpgk2/1/

```
var count = 0; //starting index
var arrayToCheck = [20, 30, 40, 20, 50]; //array to check
var condition = 100; //condition to be more than
increment(arrayToCheck, count, condition); //call function

function increment(array, index, conditionalValue) {

  var total = 0; //total to add to
  for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) { //loop through array up to index
    total += array[i]; //add value of array at index to total
  }

  if (total < conditionalValue) { //if condition is not met
    count++; //increment index
    increment(arrayToCheck, count, condition); //call function

  } else { //otherwise
    console.log('Index : ', count) //log what index condition is met
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the max outside of the reduce
var max = 20;
var hitIndex;
var count = array.reduce(function(prev, curr, index) {
                let r = prev + curr;
                // if r is less than max keep adding 
                if (r < max) { 
                 return r 
                } else {
                  // if hitIndex is undefined set it to the current index
                  hitIndex = hitIndex === undefined ? index : hitIndex;
                  return prev;
                }
            });
console.log(count, hitIndex);
```

This will leave you with the index of the first addition that would exceed the max. You could try index - 1 for the first value that did not exceed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small utility method `reduceWhile`

```
// Javascript reduceWhile implementation
function reduceWhile(predicate, reducer, initValue, coll) {
    return coll.reduce(function(accumulator, val) {
        if (!predicate(accumulator, val)) return accumulator;
        return reducer(accumulator, val);
    }, initValue)
};

function predicate(accumulator, val) {
    return val < 6;
}

function reducer(accumulator, val) {
    return accumulator += val;
}

var result = reduceWhile(predicate, reducer, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

console.log("result", result);
```